# php/mysql show data from chosen checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, where-clause

I have a table called **FRUIT**

```
id  type    daysold
1   banana  5
2   apple   6
3   apple   4
4   peach   2
5   banana  6
```

What I would like is to have 3 checkboxes:
Banana [ ]
Apple [ ]
Peach [ ]
**SUBMIT**

Then if I've only checked "Banana" and "Peach" the mysql output should only show me the rows that matches those two types. And the checkboxes should remain checked to highlight what was chosen.

I can make the checkboxes but then that's about it really. I don't know how to properly get the info from the checkboxes and down to the WHERE argument in the MYSQL-code. Especially not with two types chosen.

If it was just a dropdown menu with a single choice then I'd add the choice to the url and put *WHERE type='$choice'* - but I'm struggling with the multiple choices.

I'm a bit of a novice at both php and mysql, so I'm a bit lost on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a form like this:

```
<form action="processingPage.php" method="post" name="nameHere">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Banana" /> Banana<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Apple" /> Apple<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruit[]" value="Peach" /> Peach<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

In processingPage.php:

```
<?php
$fruits = array();
foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $fruit) {
    $fruit = mysql_real_escape_string($fruit);
    $fruits[] = "'{$fruit}'"; 
}

$sql = "select * from fruit where type in (" . implode(", ", $fruits) . ")";
//execute query and retrieve results
?>
```

Comment: I would call the fruit $fruit instead of $f. $f is bad practice in the sense of readability of code.

Comment: Can you edit your question explaining what have you tried and the precise error you are getting?

Comment: Well I basically just tried what your solution, but instead of having it go to a new page, I have kept it on the same pagea s the boxes. But nothing happens after I submit. I then tried seeing what it prints:
echo ''.$fruits.'';
And it just prints "array" - before and after I hit submit.
echo ''.$fruit.''; however prints one of the chosen fruits (But still doesn't work in the mysql query, where nothing happens, like it can't find any matches)

Comment: Try to add `print_r($_POST['fruit']);` and `print_r($fruits);` after the foreach loop and see what output it gives. Also, print out the sql query.